# Ongoing push notification in swift

Tags: android, ios, apple-push-notifications

For a feature in my app, it's critical that once a user received a push notification (while the app is in a background state) it may be closed only by clicking on *CONFIRM* (an action button) and wouldn't close or dismiss without doing so.

Is there any other way than using a widget to create ongoing push notification in and iOS environment similar to what Android Development provides `setOngoin(true)`?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  Personally, I'm glad.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have that kind of control over notification presentation. Your users will have to decide for themselves to allow you to present them alert-style notifications in the settings app.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for a way to, have an alert that pops up and doesn't go away until a confirm action is clicked?  The only thing that comes to mind is a  [UIAlertView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertview). If thats not what you are looking for , the question should be edited to provide more detail.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for. Is it possible to launch UIAlertView while app in the background?

Comment: @VirtualDevice No a UIAlertView can only be seen, while the user is inside of the app, see [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjavLCI5qHeAhUL7FMKHdNVD8cQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsourcefreeze.com%2Fuialertcontroller-ios-8-using-swift%2F&psig=AOvVaw31WcyrLRMd4i3LRwytmI9J&ust=1540563932147299)

You could create some logic related tied to the confirm action that then could queue a push notification at a set time.

Comment: Then it isn't what I need.

Comment: @VirtualDevice Read the docs I linked you and im sure you will find something. Not exactly sure what you mean then.

Comment: Your link is not even relevant to that topic. Chack then my [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setOngoing(boolean)), if you answering without understanding

Comment: @VirtualDevice Took the swift tag off your post for you. Next time you ask a question on SO please be more detailed and provided code samples etc. Android and IOS tags dont mix if you are not clear about what you want. I tried to help!